# How to call an API located on the same server?

Tags: php, rest, api, http, server

I am trying to built a web framework (school project), the framework has to be API-oriented, and I will built the web app on an API-centric architecture, using PHP :

1. The web backend will be a PHP rest API client
2. The api backend will be a PHP rest API server and the libraries
3. They will both be located on the same server, in separated folders

How do I make request to my API located on the same server ? I am afraid that making HTTP request with curl on the same server would be too heavy, what is the other alternative ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, do you want a two-tier architecture connected via REST or don't you? If you do, then you'll have to make an HTTP request, for which curl is fine. Practically speaking, no, you probably won't notice it as being "too heavy" unless you seriously screw something up.

Comment: I don't see how you would have load issues unless you are making a significant amount of requests. In that case i would look at the code for places to streamline the calls see where you can combine them etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way to to call internal api is using local ip address. so if your url is http://example.com/getdata.php then you can use http://127.0.0.1/getdata.php

Hope this will help your